# Replacement for Pondus

Tags: software-recommendation, open-source

[Pondus](https://bitbucket.org/eike/pondus) is a lightweight personal weight tracker coded in Python. I have used it for many years, but its functionality has slowly eroded with time. Some months back graphs stopped working, which made the most interesting feature of the programme. The last commit to the code base dates back to 2012, and the most recent issues were left unanswered.

Is there any open source alternative to Pondus? Preferably one that can import the data stored by Pondus (XML or CSV format).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found any alternative to Pondus. However, I've contacted Pondus' author and he migrated Pondus to Python 3. It now compiles and works on modern systems.

Source code and the new release can be found on Github:

https://github.com/enicklas/pondus